# L2 norm of homogeneous harmonic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, harmonic-functions

suppose that p is a homogeneous harmonic polynomial of k-order,i.e.$$\Delta p=0 \qquad in \mathbb{R}^{d} $$
my question is how to prove the following inequality:
$$||p||_{L^{2}(B_{2r})} \leq C(d)2^{k} ||p||_{L^{2}(B_{r})} $$
for all $r \geq 1$ .

Comment: Did you use the mean value property of harmonic function : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function?

Comment: @jvc I have tried to use the mean value property,but I don't know how to get the desired result (the ball is smaller on RHS of the inequality),and even how to use the condition"k-order polynomial".

Comment: What is the definition of k-order polynomial?

Comment: @jvc it has a form of polynomial with d variables, and every part of the polynomial is homogeneous with k-order, for example p(x,y}=x^2+y^2+xy, for d=k=2,of course ,this p is not harmonic.

Comment: Maybe just use the homogeneous property:
p(2x)=2^kp(x)